# How to create a new hash table if I have one big hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
{hashed_data = [
  {:name => "frontend", :session_total => 145, :byte => 54667},
  {:name => "backend_stagging", :session_total => 546, :byte => 895747},
  {:name => "backend", :session_total => 5468, :byte => 8957447},
  {:name => "frontend", :session_total => 54, :byte => 67387}
]
```

I must create the following hash. It does not have to be sorted.

```
hashed_data_modify = {
  :frontend => {
    :name => "frontend",
    :summary => {:session_total => 546, :byte => 54667}
    :backend => {
      :name => "backend",
      :details => {:session_total => 5468, :byte => 8957447},
      :summary => { :name => "backend_stagging", :session_total => 546, :byte => 895747 }
    }
```

that is, create a new key: `frontend` where `hashed_data[:name] == "frontend"` and create a key: `backend` where `hashed_data[:name] == "backend"`. The `frontend` key contains only the data for the `frontend` data and for the `backend` only the `backend`.

I tried my `sorting_method`, it is bad:

```
hashed_data.select do |h|  
  if (h[:name] == "frontend") then
    return hash = {
      :frontend => {
        :name => hashed_data[:name],
        :details => [:session_total => hashed_data[:stot], :byte_in => hashed_data[:bin]]
      }
    } # :name => "frontend" etc.
    (h[:name == "backend")     
    return hash = {
      :backend => {:name => hashed_data[:name] #:name => "backend"}
    } etc.
  end
end
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What is the logic behind? For example, why is `frontend/summary/session_bytes == 546` when the original hash didn't have this value nor sums up to this value? Why is there a `summary` sub-hash in `:frontend`, `details` in `:backend`, but not in `:backend_stagging`. Please explain why and how you need the hash values merged.

Comment: As well as providing a better explanation of what you want to do (by editing the question), please double-check the values in `hashed_data` and in the hash you wish to construct.

Comment: You seem to have posted the question and walked away, assuming readers would require no clarification. Needless to say that was a bad assumption. Now, almost one hour since you posted the question, there are three votes to close it, because it is not clear. In future please put more effort into writing a clear and complete question, and hang around to respond to comments.

Comment: To set off code either indent four spaces or (better) format as desired, then select code and click on `{}` in edit bar above your code. Ruby's standard indent is two spaces. `then` is optional and normally not used with `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you want.

```
hashed_data.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.
            map { |_,v| v.max_by { |g| g[:session_total] } }
  #=> [{:name=>"frontend", :session_total=>145, :byte=>54667},
  #    {:name=>"backend_stagging", :session_total=>546, :byte=>895747},
  #    {:name=>"backend", :session_total=>5468, :byte=>8957447}]
```

Note that the first calculation is the following.

```
hashed_data.group_by { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> {"frontend"=>[{:name=>"frontend", :session_total=>145, :byte=>54667},
  #                 {:name=>"frontend", :session_total=>54, :byte=>67387}],
  #    "backend_stagging"=>[{:name=>"backend_stagging", :session_total=>546,
  #                          :byte=>895747}],
  #    "backend"=>[{:name=>"backend", :session_total=>5468, :byte=>8957447}]}
```

Firstly, you say you want the first element of the array returned to be:

```
{:name=>"frontend", :session_total=>546, :byte=>54667}
```

I'm guessing the value of `:session_total` is a typo, and should be `145`.

Secondly, I assume when two or more hashes have the same value of `:name` (here just `"frontend"`), you want to keep the one for which the value `session_total` is greatest (but that's a truly wild guess).

Thirdly, you seem to want to change the value `"backend_staging"` to the key `:summary`. If so, that's not central to the question and just a nuisance for those giving answers, so I've disregarded that requirement.

Comment: I want to create hashed_data_modify  key: frontend where hashed_data[:name] == "frontend" and create a key: backend where hashed_data[:name] == "backend". Separate the data

Comment: Wow wild shot in the dark and a green check mark to boot. I have no idea how you interpreted the question and desired response into anything at all

Comment: @engineersmnky, it's not much different than "given the first five values of a sequence that follow, what are the next three values in the sequence?"

Comment: @CarySwoveland given the fact that neither your response structure nor your data matches the proposed requirement, I'd say it is more like "If I have one hand behind my back, what number am I thinking of"

Comment: I also have remote mind-meld powers. For example, you are now thinking of someone named "‎Tatiana".